# C# Post to 3rd party API with parameters and inline file

Tags: c#, httpclient

The API I'm posting to is requesting this:
`curl "https://api.geocod.io/v1.7/lists?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY" \` your text `-F "file"="@sample_list.csv" \`your text `-F "direction"="forward" \`your text  `-F "format"="{{A}} {{B}} {{C}} {{D}}" \`

What I've written is below but I'm getting a 400 Bad Request response.

(the csvFile is IFormFile)

```
`var httpClient = new HttpClient();
`var baseUri = "https://api.geocod.io/v1.7/lists?"
            
    using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                //set up the parameters
                var query = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    ["api_key"] = "My_API_Key",
                    ["direction"] = "forward",
                    ["format"] = "{{C}} {{D}} {{E}} {{F}}"
                };
                //base uri
                var uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUri, query);
                //load the file
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await csvFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
                //add the file
                multipartFormContent.Add(fileStreamContent, name: "file", fileName: fileNameForStorage);
                //send it
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, multipartFormContent);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://www.geocod.io/docs/?shell#geocoding-lists), the fields 'direction' and 'format' should be sent as form fields (in the body) where you're trying to send them as querystring fields.

These values should go in a separate `FormUrlEncodedContent` object:

```
var formValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
formValues.Add("direction", "forward");
formValues.Add("format", "{{C}} {{D}} {{E}} {{F}}");
var form = new FormUrlEncodedContent();
multipartFormContent.Add( form);
```

Comment: According to [the curl docs](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) `-F` "lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button"

Comment: @nilsK that's right, the C# HttpClient equivalent is to add a`FormUrlEncodedContent` to the multipart content. I've added example code.

Comment: Thanks @Simmetric.  If I understand this correctly, the api key is still sent as a querystring field and the 'direction' and 'format' are send as FormUrlEncodedContent.  The filename should also be added that way.  But I'm a little confused then as to whether I'm handling the csvFile correctly.

Comment: You're correct. As for the file, going by the docs it seems you're doing it right. There is an alternative way (include the file as a form field) but for large files that seems less feasible. Are you still getting errors?

Comment: I apologize for the delay in answering.  Yes, I am still getting an error but it seems to be a timeout error in uploading the file.  The majority of the time, this file will 50-100kb in size.  I'm reading the iFormFile into MemoryStream but most everything I've read gives examples of files saved to server first and then read into the stream.  Does this make a difference?  Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. IFormFile is meant to be consumed as a stream in some way. If you want to be sure, you could always store the file to disk first and then open a FileStream from there. Is the timeout coming from the API or does it happen before that? The file size range you mention is very small and should not pose any problems.